# Does using Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke inherently provide mutually exclusive access to a section of code?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a function similar to the following:

```
public void Increment()
{
    if (Count == 0)
    {
        AttachResource();
    }

    Count++;
}
```

Changes to my code mean that this function will be called from multiple threads. Due to the nature of AttachResource(), this function must be run on the main thread.

Assume I modify the function to be as follows:

```
public void Increment()
{
    _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (Count == 0)
        {
            AttachResource();
        }

        Count++;
    }));
}
```

Do I need to also add a lock to this code to ensure mutually exclusive access by threads? Or will the call through the dispatcher naturally accomplish this by serializing multiple calls onto the main thread?

Comment: Any resource that's accessed from code that runs only on one particular thread never requires protection with a lock.  There's nothing that could ever be locked-out.

Comment: Thanks all! The sanity check of my approach is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples will prevent AttachResource from being called more than once unless something else resets Count.

Other than that, assuming Dispatcher is the UI's dispatcher instance (e.g. `Application.Current.Dispatcher`), then only the UI thread will invoke AttachResource from this code path.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the referenced _dispatcher is for the main UI thread.

Comment: In that case no lock is needed, but as I mentioned the use of Count only allows this to be run once, ever, unless Count is reset to 0 elsewhere.

Comment: There's a comparable Decrement function that I didn't list. I'm doing a very basic form of reference counting for a shared resource.

Comment: You are good with your second example then, assuming that the decrement function also marshals to the UI thread.  If you want to be utterly sure, look into Interlocked.Increment and Interlocked.Decrement or the Semaphore class.